# Question about proving the existence of an arbitrage opportunity

Tags: option-pricing, arbitrage

I am having a hard time understanding the reasoning behind a statement in the proof  of the following lemma from page 14 (228) of the paper "[Martingales and stochastic integrals in the theory of continuous trading](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304414981900260)" by Harrison and Pliska in 1981.

Lemma: If there exists a self-financing strategy $\phi$ (not necessarily admissible) with $V_{0}(\phi)=0, V_{T}(\phi)\geq 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[V_{T}(\phi)]>0 $, then there exists an arbitrage opportunity.

Here the admissible stands for $V(\phi)\geq 0$,  $\phi,S\in\mathbb{R}^n $ and $V_t(\phi)=\phi_t\cdot S_t$ which is a scalar product.

Proof: If $V(\phi)\geq 0$, then $\phi$ is admissible and hence is an arbitrage opportunity itself, and we are done. Otherwise there must exist $t<T,A\in\mathcal{F_t}$ such that $\phi_t\cdot S_t=a<0$ on $A$ and $\phi_u\cdot S_u\leq 0$ on $A$ for all $u>t$.

Here $\phi_t\in\mathcal{F_{t-1}}$ and $ S_t \in \mathcal{F_{t}}$

What I don't understand is why all values after a given time $t$ have to be non-positive.

My intuition tells me that I should have some which are non-positive, but not necessarily consecutively. And also the statement contradicts $ V_{T}(\phi)\geq 0$ in my opinion.

With this, I want to create a new strategy which is both self financing and admissible. The problem with taking $t$ non-consecutive is that the new strategy doesn't satisfy either the admissibility condition or the self-financing condition.

I also suspect that $\phi_u\cdot S_u\leq 0$  is a typo and it should be $\phi_u\cdot S_u\geq 0$.

Comment: What is the source for the Lemma?

Comment: Hello, here is the link to the paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304414981900260 (lemma under theorem 2.7)